# If I have a bag that contains 95 white balls and 5 red balls, what are the odds I draw 10 white balls? Or 4 white and 1 red, etc?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The order in which the balls are drawn does not matter; I care only about the final ratio of colors given a draw of $n$ balls. Correcting something I had earlier posted here, I *do* have replacement.

I recognize this is probably a straightforward combinatorics problem, but it has been decades since I studied combinatorics and I can't puzzle it out analytically. I have solved this problem via Monte Carlo methods (e.g. given $12$ picks, there's a $54%$ chance that all are white), but I would prefer to see the proper solution.

Comment: Are you choosing with or without replacement?  Guessing you mean "without replacement", then for $12$ choices the probability that all are white is $\binom {95}{12}\big/ \binom {100}{12}\approx .52$  similar methods apply to your other questions.

Comment: Note, if you are choosing *with* replacement then your test case would have probability $.95^{12}=.54$ which more closely matches your simulation.  So I think your simulator is replacing the balls.  If you did a good Monte Carlo simulation, you ought to be closer.

Comment: @Lulu your observation is correct, and thinking over the problem I realize my question here was in error and the Monte Carlo was finding the right answer; I do have replacement. What is the general form for the solution with replacement?

Comment: With replacement, to get exactly $n$ white balls out of a choice of $n+m$, the probability is $\binom {n+m}n \times .95^n\times .05^m$

Comment: @Lulu you are my hero. I got close but couldn't quite get there. Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: The OP is changed, the original version is WITHOUT replacement, now you change it WITH replacement. Do NOT change your OP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The intent of the question, as reflected in the simulated results, was to allow replacement.  Thus, every draw is independent of all others, and yields White with probability $.95$ and red with probability $.05$

In that situation, the probability of drawing exactly $n$ white balls out of a draw of $n+m$ total balls is $$\binom {n+m}n\times .95^n\times .05^m$$

and the process is governed by the classical [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: The OP is changed completely, to answer it is to connive this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to draw $x$ white balls and $y$ red balls, the probability is

$$P=\frac{\binom{95}{x}\cdot\binom{5}{y}}{\binom{100}{x+y}}$$

**Explanation:**

Denominator is the total ways you can draw for $x+y$ balls from $100$ balls. Numerator is the favored ways, i.e. you want $x$ white balls, then you draw $x$ from $95$. You want $y$ red balls, then you draw $y$ from $5$.

Comment: This answer was written when the question stated that the balls were selected without replacement.